# How to get Custom picklist field value of User object in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-field, picklist, user

I need to get the Custom Piclist Field (RecordDefaultCountry__c) from user object in VF page javascript.So I used,

```
> if(('{!$User.RecordDefaultCountry__c}' == 'Germany'))
```

Its throwing an error:

> Error: Field RecordDefaultCountry__c is a picklist field. Picklist
>
> fields are only supported in certain functions. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/htdoor?loc=help&target=tips_on_building_formulas.htm%23picklists_and_msps&section=Customizing&language=en_US&release=202.13.1&instance=CS87',
>   'Help', 1024, 768,
>   'width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,directories=no,location=yes,dependant=no',
>   false, false);">Tell me more

So Please provide me solution for this.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really amazing to see that Salesforce is providing help link with the error ;)

So basically [it says](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm&language=en_US) that **picklist fields support only following functions:**

1. **ISPICKVAL**
2. **CASE**
3. **TEXT**

For your need you can apply this:

```
'{!ISPICKVAL($user.RecordDefaultCountry__c,'Germany')}'
```

Comment: Its working.....